# Creating a HTML index of documents (PDF,PS) for a knowledge base

Tags: indexing, pdf, knowledge-base, documents

I've been looking for a command line / Linux-friendly "index" generator. I want to load PDF, PS, DOC and other documents and generate a static (X)HTML frame-based interface, as a knowledge base of sorts. Essentially I will rely on the individual having a PDF plugin installed on the browser.

A tool like this would come very handy for us.

Comment: A few lines of script should take care of this.

Comment: The documents might not provide any relevant information in their filenames at all.

Comment: What a pity it's impossible to programmatically extract metadata from files.  I'll note that your question makes no mention of this requirement, either.

Comment: Not sure if your comment is ironical, condescending, both things, or none at all, but it sure isn't helpful or constructive.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many solutions out there for document management; are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel? Personally, I'd recommend Knowledge Tree (there's a free community version).

If you've got your heart set on web page full of file links, you probably want to do it web-side, so it's dynamic and you don't have to remember to re-run it when you put new files in.

Something like the PHP Directory Listing script here might be best: 
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script